# What Duolingo-like resources are there for learning Hindi?

Tags: resource-request, electronic-resources, hindi

I'm looking for free desktop or mobile applications that have an approach to learning Hindi that is similar to Duolingo's, in that it has a primary gamification aspect. I have tried several, but very few are free. What Duolingo-like apps are there for learning Hindi?

Answer (score 5):

After the question was asked, the Duolingo Hindi course has been completed and is now in public beta: https://www.duolingo.com/course/hi/en/Learn-Hindi-Online

Answer (score 2):

I have found one free app that at least has a game aspect, although it is not clear whether the entire learning experience is gamified: [Learn Hindi™](http://appcrawlr.com/ios/learn-hindi-ilang) claims to use an "Addicting game to improve learners' memory" and also contains quiz games. A potential downside is that its primary audience is children.

Other free apps that I have seen don't seem to rely on gamification or translations:

- [LEARN HINDI STEP BY STEP](https://www.socialapphub.com/app/learn-hindi-step-step) "presents every Hindi sentence, word, or grammar with examples for each of them making the application user-friendly". Presenting words etc. in context is good, but the app is not like Duolingo.
- [Language 101 for Android, iPhone, iPad and Kindle Fire](https://www.hindipod101.com/apps/) gives you "access to 100s of audio and video lessons made by real teachers, lesson notes, learning tools and more". This does not sound similar to Duolingo either.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to warn that the Duolingo Hindi app is pretty awful. The audio is really unclear. I had a native speaker listen to it and they couldn't tell what was being said. It's also buggy. Someone on r/LanguageLearning wrote an extensive review detailing its flaws:
https://www.reddit.com/r/languagelearning/comments/grmzd7/why_im_quitting_duolingo_and_everything_thats/

I know you are looking for free apps, but if you change your mind the Rosetta Stone Hindi app is good.
https://www.rosettastone.com/learn-hindi/

It's only gives 6 weeks worth of lessons. But it combines audio and visual queues alongside Hindi phrases and gamification, which has been proven to be an efficient way to learn a new language. I believe it's $15 a month.